# how to insert large data into database using json string in laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have 4 tables in my database, assume their names A,B,C,D.
I am trying to store data into those 4 tables using json string provided by api request.
Each table has 8 columns. Considering column names as A1,A2,A3...A8 , B1,B2,B3...B8 , C1...C8 ,D1..D8.

Snippet of controller:

```
 $requestData = $request->json()->all();
  $aModel= A::create($requestData);
  $bModel= B::create($requestData);
  $cModel= C::create($requestData);
  $dModel= D::create($requestData);
```

All four tables have different columns and no relationships between them.
When I am trying to execute the above code i get the exception that; Column B1 does not exists in table A.

My question here is, how can i insert data into multiple tables with single json request with minimum code?

Before posting this question i have found few posts where we can do this by using Arr::except() to remove columns which are not needed and another way is to selecting each columns for model like aModel->A1,aModel->A2 , aModel->save(), however both these ways are not best for me to implement in my case. I am expecting a code where the query will only take necessary data from array and insert into table.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use `fill()`

```php
$requestData = $request->json()->all();

$aModel = new A;
$aModel->fill($requestData)->save();

$bModel = new B;
$bModel->fill($requestData)->save();

$cModel = new C;
$cModel->fill($requestData)->save();

$dModel = new D;
$dModel->fill($requestData)->save();
```

Comment: thanks for the comment. i will try to implement it and give feedback.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, be sure that your eloquent model is using the fillable property

```
class A extends Model {
    $fillable = array(
         'C1',
         'C2', //and so on
    );
}
```

This way when you do

$aModel = new A($requestData);

Or

$aModel = new A();
$aModel->fill($requestData);

It will only add the columns declared as fillable.

Be wary of other situations your tables can be filled directly from request data though as users would be free enter what they like.

If you are using $guarded instead of $fillable this would be the exact opposite and you would have to declare what columns to allow rather than what to not allow by filling. Not ideal for your situation and fillable would be best

See more about fillable here https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#inserting-and-updating-models

If possible I would instead recommend changing the way your api receives it's data, perhaps as four different multi level arrays to match with your tables and make it easier for you to control what data goes to what table and also prevent headache later when you wanna make some changes to your database columns and for example there may be a repeating column for multiple tables